# How to remove the Border in image sprite

Tags: html, css

Border is not removing in the below code, which is image sprite . I have tried some methods to remove the border using style and border 0 ,but no use .

```
<style>
img.home{width:40px;height:32px;
background:url(share.png) 0 0;
border-style: none;}
img.next{width:40px;
height:32px;background:url(share.png) -36px 0;
border-style:none;}
</style>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">
<img class="home" border="0">
</a>
<img class="next" border="0"/>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/anbD8/)

Comment: ya http://jsfiddle.net/GB54f/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images come with a default border, that only disappears when the image is downloaded. That image comes from the `src` attribute of the image. If no src is set, then the image won't be downloaded, and the border will be forever there - your case exactly.

A normal img tag looks like this:

```
<img src="/something.jpg" />
```

yours looks like this:

```
<img />
```

You're adding your image through css's background-image. Not as it should be done. You can add a background image, but it's usually for other purposes. (check the aside at the bottom).

Try removing the background image and placing the image location on the src attribute of the image. Like this:

```
<img class="next" src="/share.png" />
```

You'll see the image has no border now.

**Aside**
When a background image is added to an img element, it's usually to provide a placeholder image for when no img `src` is set. Think of avatars on the comments section of a blog.

**Also**
When creating a sprite, you can use `div`s `p`s `em`s etc. Remember, the `background-image` can be applied to any element!

Comment: It's not working because the image location you set on the src points to no image. That results in the same. Take a look -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/GB54f/20/

Comment: Ok, when you're using sprites you don't use img tags. Try instead, using a `div`, a `button`, a `span` an `a` or something else - whatever you want. Sprites are not meant to be used on img tags. Remember! The `background-image` property can be applied to any element.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your html tag is `<img class="somthing" />` and in the class "something" you have defined the background position of the image.

As you select a particular image from the image sprite more accurately, a particular position where the image is. Your class is proper where you fetch the image using the background position in css.

A simple solution to remove the border is just make the `img` tag as a `div`.

if you fetch the image according to the background position why it is necessary to use a `img` tag.

Just write the html like ...`<div class="next" ..>`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a base64 very small transparent image, if you would not use an external file

```
<img class="next"  src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it out, JOPLOmacedo was right, but you don't have to remove the background, just use the `src` tag. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GB54f/21/). (Sorry about the images, but I needed them to test the `src`)

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">
<img class="home" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" border="0"/>
 </a>
<img class="next" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/social-icons/facebook_16.png" border="0"/>​
```

CSS:

```
img.home{width:40px;height:32px;
border: none; background:url(http://farm1.staticflickr.com/111/315308766_163c08db38.jpg) 0 0;}
img.next{width:40px;
height:32px;
border:none; float: right;
background:url(http://farm1.staticflickr.com/111/315308766_163c08db38.jpg) -36 0;}​
```

Comment: I didn't say you had to remove the background. I suggested removing the image, since he wouldn't be needing it for what he wanted to do. My aside at the bottom even suggests an use for the background-image on an img element.

Comment: Yes, sorry posted before I saw that